# How do you increment an assigned variable in smarty without displaying it

Tags: php, smarty

So I have an assigned variable in smarty:

```
{assign var=number value=0}
```

Now I can increment it using

```
{$number++}
```

or

```
{++$number}
```

Which is exactly what I need, only problem is, it displays the value of $number on the page.
Is there a way I can increment the value but not display it?

This is not used inside of a loop otherwise I would use something like iteration or index.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You could do this:

```
{assign var=val value=1}
{assign var=val value=$val+1}
{$val} // displays 2
```

The above will be compiled to:

```
$this->assign('val', 1);
$this->assign('val', $this->_tpl_vars['val']+1);
echo $this->_tpl_vars['val'];
```

or

```
{assign var=var value=1}
{capture assign=var}{$var+1}{/capture}
{$var} // displays 2
```

Which in turn will be compiled as:

```
$this->assign('var', 1);
ob_start();
echo $this->_tpl_vars['var']+1;
$this->_smarty_vars['capture']['default'] = ob_get_contents();
$this->assign('var', ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();
echo $this->_tpl_vars['var'];
```

another approach would be to write a small plugin:

```
// plugins/function.inc.php
function smarty_function_inc($params, Smarty &$smarty)
{
   $params['step'] = empty($params['step']) ? 1 : intval($params['step']);

   if (empty($params['var'])) {
      trigger_error("inc: missing 'var' parameter");
      return;
   }
   if (!in_array($params['var'], array_keys($smarty->_tpl_vars))) {
      trigger_error("inc: trying to increment unassigned variable " . $params['var']);
      return;
   }
   if (isset($smarty->_tpl_vars[$params['var']])) {
      $smarty->assign($params['var'],
      $smarty->_tpl_vars[$params['var']] + $params['step']);
   }
}
```

The function would then be called like this, notice that `step` is optional and if not given the variable will be incremented by one:

```
{assign var=var value=0}
{inc var=var step=2}
{$var} // displays 2
```

**Reference**
[Smarty {assign}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl)
[Smarty {capture}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.capture.tpl)
[Extending Smarty With Plugins](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.functions.tpl)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I prefer the 2nd one using capture. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

It's cleaner just to do it like this...

```
{$number = $number +1}
```

Comment: True, but this will display it (which is not a intended outcome)

Comment: It won't display it.

Answer (score 5):

Better to use the built in Smarty "counter" >> `{counter}` element.

So, in template you can use:

```
<div>Some text, html code, whatever... </div>
{* init the counter! *}
{counter start=0 print=false} {* now the tpl doesn't show the "0" number *}


{* 3x run :D *}
{some_cyclic_stuff_like_foreach_or_section}
    Run the counter: {counter}
{/some_cyclic_stuff_like_foreach_or_section}
```

It will print for you:

```
Run the counter: 1
Run the counter: 2
Run the counter: 3
```

So, at least, you can use it with the `print=false` option, and you have the counter but it's hidden.

If you use it the "variable way" (like the upper section write) you also can hide it with html/css or just simply don't let it print  :)

Comment: The original post states "This is not used inside of a loop". You appear to be using a loop.

Answer (score -1):

If I had to do this I would do something like the following: `{php}$number++{/php}` but it is very ugly to have to use php in a smarty template. This might suggest that there is a better way of doing what you planned to do.

Comment: I thought of this as well and got it working very nicely with PHP, but I wasn't sure how to increment a variable assigned through smarty, so I ended up using php in several places throughout the template to assign the variable, then increment it as needed, then later on to actually use it - it got kind of ugly, although I'll drop back to that if I don't have any better solutions.

Comment: Is there a reason that you couldn't do all the legwork in the php and assign a load of variables/arrays? What you want to do is a lot of work for the template and completely defeats the purpose of using smarty.

Comment: One bit of information I forgot to put in here is that I'm using a while loop in the template. After your latest comment, I came to the realization that I could increment the number in the {while} tag {while $number++ < 3} - headpalm moment. Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to increment the array index by 1 as it starts with 0 in most languages. This is how I did in Smarty and eZPublish `{$index|inc(1)}`. Now the first element index shows 1 instead of 0 in the printed table.